# Configuring the Raspberry Pi to use various protected WiFi spots

Tags: wifi, usb, wpa

The use case is this: the Pi will periodically ping my server. If it gets the go-ahead, it will perform some action using a relay. Otherwise it'll remain dormant.

I need to install multiple RP3s at multiple locations. I don't know what the WiFi passwords are until I get there and I'd rather not lug around an entire set of screen+mouse+keyboard.

Can't SSH into it until it's connected to the WiFi though.

What's the easiest way to have the Pi connect to an unfamiliar network without a screen/keyboard?

I was thinking maybe I can save the network name / pass in a USB file and, on boot, if there's no internet, check USBs for these files and attempt a connection.

The downside is that I'll have to have one USB per "installed" Pi.

I'm puzzled. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I think your idea is fine. Just copy the credentials from the USB to the Pi with a script, and then you can remove the USB.

One way to do it would be to

1. Check if there is an USB mounted
2. If so, copy the WiFi credentials from the USB

Put this in your `crontab` under the directive `@reboot`, and you should be fine. You edit your crontab with the command `sudo crontab -e`.

Even better would be to run the script to copy the credentials every time you mount a USB. You can create a `udev`-rule for this. Check [this question over at AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25071/how-to-run-a-script-when-a-specific-flash-drive-is-mounted) for examples.